# WordPress 3.7 [embed] - not work working

Tags: wordpress, youtube

I am having an issue with a plugin that I work on for WordPress. It should embed YouTube, Vimeo, SoundCloud and more based on the URL provided by the user.

The embed in WP should be very easy like: 
    [embed width="640" height="480]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpVUIwrNLoo[/embed]

The thing is that this is not working at all.

```
echo do_shortcode('[embed width="640" height="480]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpVUIwrNLoo[/embed]');
```

Thank you,
Marius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`wp_oembed_get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get) ?

Your code would be like:

```
$videourl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpVUIwrNLoo';
$htmlcode = wp_oembed_get($videourl);

echo $htmlcode;
```